# How to induct this problem $1-x^k < (1-x)k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is a question I saw in Lax's calculus book. Although Lax's guidance is very good, I still can't understand this formula through mathematical induction.

The text:

> (d) In this last part you need to explain through a sequence of steps, outlined below,
> why $g_{n}−e_{n}$ is less than $\frac{4}{n}$ and hence tends to $0$. First recall that for $0 < x < 1$,we have the inequality
> $$
> 1-x^k=(1-x)(1+x+\dots+x^{k-1})<(1-x)k.
> $$

Comment: For the inequality, we only need to recognize that if $0<x<1$, $0<x^n<1$ for any positive integer $n$. $(1+x+\cdots+x^{k-1})$ is a sum of $k$ terms that are all less than or equal to 1.

Comment: For the claim $1-x^k = (1-x)(1+x_\cdots+x^{k-1})$, just multiply it out:
$(1-x)(1+x_\cdots+x^{k-1}) = (1+x_\cdots+x^{k-1}) - (x+x^2_\cdots+x^k) = 1-x^k$.

No need for induction.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand, the one on the left grows slower than the one on the right. Maybe I'm out of my mind today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equality holds because

$$(1-x)(1+x+\dots+x^{k-1})=(1-x)+(x-x^2)+\ldots+(x^{k-1}-x^k)=1-x^k.$$

If $x\in(0,1)$, you find
$$0< x^n = x\cdot \ldots \cdot x< 1 \cdot \ldots \cdot 1 = 1^n = 1$$

for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Therefore

$$0<(1+x+\dots+x^{k-1})<(1+1+\dots+1) = k.$$

This yields

$$1-x^k=(1-x)(1+x+\dots+x^{k-1})<(1-x)k.$$

Comment: Thank you, sir. I feel intimidated by k and n.I'm much better now.

Comment: You are welcome! Saying $x^n<1$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is just a shorter way of saying that $x^1<1$, $x^2<1$, $x^3<1$, ..., and $x^{k-1}<1$.